# Encontrar el código fuente del método get_result de la extensión mysqlnd

Tags: php, mysql

Estuve buscando el código fuente del método `get_result` de la extensión `mysqlnd`, pero no lo encontré, revisando el [repositorio de la extensión en Github](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/mysqlnd).

Busqué en los siguientes archivos:

- `mysqlnd.h`
- `mysqlnd_commands.c`
- `mysqlnd_commands.h`
- `mysqlnd_driver.c`
- `mysqlnd_result.c`
- `mysqlnd_result.h`
- `php_mysqlnd.c`
- `php_mysqlnd.h`

Y en otros archivos que ahora no recuerdo.

¿Alguien tiene idea de dónde encontrarlo?

Comment: Tienes algun problema o es pura curiosidad cibernetica :)??

Comment: Es algo relacionado con [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967), quisiera ver cómo funciona el método internamente para re-escribirlo y poder usarlo en servidores que no tengan la extensión `mysqlnd` instalada.

Comment: Está solo el prototipo, pero no el código. [`func_mysqlnd_stmt__get_result get_result;`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_structs.h#L767)

Comment: Eso lo vi @ArtEze pero el método tendría que estar en alguna parte.

Comment: @A.Cedano y que buscaste? que encontraste?  que viste que no servia? asi no buscamos todos lo mismo que vos...

Comment: @gbianchi edité la pregunta poniendo los archivos en los que recuerdo haber buscado. Quisiera ver cómo funciona internamente ese método sea en el repositorio o en otra fuente.

Answer (score 1):

fíjate en este Link de búsqueda: [Link](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=get_result&type=)
Como veras en una de las extenciones:
`ext/mysqli/mysqli_fe.c` esta definida la funcion como alias, exactamente en la linea 658: [Link](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/8d54f98e3312ebb3b683b4a92e38e5ed038782e8/ext/mysqli/mysqli_fe.c#L658)

si consideras que utiliza un alias para el método:

```
PHP_FALIAS(get_result, mysqli_stmt_get_result, arginfo_mysqli_no_params)
```

y hacemos la búsqueda en el repositorio: `mysqli_stmt_get_result` encontraremos en este archivo: [Link](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/fd57ee89310abc9939f7ce88b282feeb4fc0eb97/ext/mysqli/mysqli_nonapi.c#L874) el cual contiene en la linea 874 una funcion similar:

```
PHP_FUNCTION(mysqli_stmt_get_result)
```

** Actualizacion **

Como veo tu comentario si quieres saber como funciona el método tendrás que desgranar cada sub-metodo que utiliza la funcion para poder saber que hace... en teoría se supone que utilizara métodos nativos para manejo de datos etc...

```
if (zend_parse_method_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS(), getThis(), "O", &mysql_stmt, mysqli_stmt_class_entry) == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }
    MYSQLI_FETCH_RESOURCE_STMT(stmt, mysql_stmt, MYSQLI_STATUS_VALID);

    if (!(result = mysqlnd_stmt_get_result(stmt->stmt))) {
        MYSQLI_REPORT_STMT_ERROR(stmt->stmt);
        RETURN_FALSE;
    }

    mysqli_resource = (MYSQLI_RESOURCE *)ecalloc (1, sizeof(MYSQLI_RESOURCE));
    mysqli_resource->ptr = (void *)result;
    mysqli_resource->status = MYSQLI_STATUS_VALID;
    MYSQLI_RETURN_RESOURCE(mysqli_resource, mysqli_result_class_entry);
```

Espero te ayude.

Comment: Sin embargo, no logro ver cómo funciona internamente el método, que es lo que me interesa.

Comment: tu pregunta esta resuelta: **Encontrar el código fuente del método get_result de la extensión mysqlnd** el entender como funcionan las entrañas es un tema que no corresponde a esta web.