# get_result() no reconocido

Tags: php

Buen dia!!

estoy haciendo un autocomplete para un input en con ajax por medio de php  y mysql, el tutorial aqui por si desean verlo

https://phppot.com/jquery/bootstrap-autocomplete-with-dynamic-data-load-using-php-ajax/

### el php adaptandolo a mi base de datos

```
<?php
require('conectar.php');
    $keyword = strval($_POST['query']);
    $search_param = "{$keyword}%";
    $sql = $conexion->prepare("SELECT distinct nombre_cliente FROM cuentas WHERE nombre_cliente LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%' ORDER BY nombre_cliente ASC");
    $sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)
  {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resultado_nombre_cliente[] = $row["nombre_cliente"];
        }
        echo json_encode($resultado_nombre_cliente);
    }
    $conexion->close();
?>
```

---

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in
>   /home2/gabriel/perezrodriguezabogados.com/sistema/PHP/autocompletar.php:8

he leido que hay que instalar algo de un controlador pero  estoy usando cpanel en una cuenta de hosting común, en este caso hostgator y no se si se pueda hacer eso

hay otra manera de escribirlo y que me haga lo requerido?

dejo por si acaso el script aunque no creo sea necesario

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#input_nombre_cliente').typeahead({
            source: function (query, result)
            {
              $.ajax({
                url: "../PHP/autocompletar.php",
                data: 'query=' + query,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data)
                {
                  result($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return item;
                  }));
                }
              });
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Si puedes indenta tus lineas de código 4 espacios desde el principio y separalas con sus respectivos saltos de línea. Para que todo se pueda entender mejor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### El problema

El Manual de PHP dice lo siguiente sobre `get_result`:

> #### MySQL Native Driver Only
>
> Disponible sólo con [`mysqlnd`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqlnd.php).

O sea, que si no tienes instalado el drive `mysqlnd`, la función `get_result` no estará disponible, como de hecho está ocurriendo, por eso el mensaje: `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()...`

---

### La solución

Dado que estás en un hosting compartido, puede que tengas dificultades para instalar el driver `mysqlnd`. Podrías de todos modos explorar esa posibilidad, contactando con el servicio técnico de tu hosting, **si te interesan más funciones de dicho driver**.

Ahora bien, si solamente te interesa el uso de `get_result`, puedes optar por una solución más simple: **implementar tu propia función `get_result`**. Se trata de una función *handmade*  que hace lo mismo que `get_result`.

Dicha función [fue propuesta por @aldanux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114105/29967) como respuesta a la pregunta: [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967). Es una solución interesante, para evitar escribir un código que quizá no funcione en algunos entornos que no tengan `mysqlnd` instalado :

```
function get_result( $stmt ) {
    $arrResult = array();
    $stmt->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $stmt->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $arrParams = array();
        while ( $field = $metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $arrParams[] = &$arrResult[ $i ][ $field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_result' ), $arrParams );
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
    return $arrResult;
}
```

Esta función la puedes usar:

- sea en el mismo script donde recuperas los datos
- sea poniéndola en una `Clase` utilitaria, donde colocas todas tus funciones utilitarias. Esta sería la forma más recomendada, sobre todo en aplicaciones grandes. De ese modo, tienes la función en un solo sitio y cuando la necesites creas una instancia de dicha `Clase` utilitaria.

**Modo de uso**

Sería muy sencillo. Le pasas a la función el `$stmt` y ésta te devuelve un array asociativo con los resultados.

Tomando tu código, sería algo así:

```
$result = get_result($sql);
```

Para comprobar si no hubo resultados, no necesitarás invocar `num_rows`, podrás hacerlo simplemente así:

```
if ($result) {
//hubo resultados. Los leemos...
    foreach ($result as $row){
        $resultado_nombre_cliente[] = $row["nombre_cliente"];
    }
echo json_encode($resultado_nombre_cliente);    
}else{
echo "No se encontraron datos";
}
```

P. D.: Por si queda alguna duda, [aquí hay un ejemplo completo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132176/29967), donde se implementa esta función.

Comment: Excelente amigo, justo lo que necesitaba, gracias!

Comment: @GabrielUribeGomez Me alegro de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema. Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.