# No MysqlInd no funciona fetch_assoc ni get_result()

Tags: php, mysqli

No tengo `mysqlInd` entonces no funciona `fetch_assoc` muestra Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() ni `get_result()` Siguiendo esta [solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132176/48421) estoy intentando almacenar todas las columnas de la fila consultada en una sesión la `$_SESSION['usuario']`para después consultar columna por columna así `$_SESSION['usuario']['email']`  como imitando al `fetch_assoc` pero se almacenan como único array no se diferencian entre las columnas si no que se guardan todas juntas

```
$email=(empty($_POST['email']))    ? NULL : $_POST['email'];
$pwd  =(empty($_POST['password'])) ? NULL : $_POST['password'];

if ($email && $pwd && $conn){
    $sql='SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE email=? AND password=?';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$pwd);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $filas=$stmt->num_rows;
        if($filas>0){
            $arrDatos=$stmt->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$arrDatos;
            header('Location: consola.php');
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No se encontraron registros";
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error en la consulta: ".$stmt->error;
    }   
}
else
{
    echo "Falta alguno de los datos del POST o la conexión es nula";
}
function myGetResult( $Statement ) {
    $RESULT = array();
    $Statement->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
        $PARAMS = array();
        while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
        $Statement->fetch();
    }
    return $RESULT;
}
```

¿Algún consejo?

Comment: ¿Dónde está el fetch_assoc en el código compartido? MySQLi tiene una función para hacer eso ([`mysqli_fetch_assoc o mysqli_resut::fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)), ¿no te funciona?

Comment: no esta porque cuando lo coloqué no funcionaba muestra error `fatal error: call to undefined method mysqli::fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Ok, quizás lo estabas aplicando en el sitio equivocado, se tiene que aplicar al resultado y no a la conexión (que parece que es el error que mencionas). ¿Podrías poner lo que intentaste?

Comment: No, lo aplique a `$stmt` y no funciona

Comment: `$stmt` es la consulta, no el resultado. Si añades lo que intentaste y te dio fallo, seguro que podemos resolver esto en poco tiempo.

Comment: listos ya lo cambie

Comment: Prueba a usar `$arrDatos=$stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79138/discussion-between-ger-and-alvaro-montoro).

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro `fetch_assoc` no funciona con consultas preparadas en `mysqli`, solamente con `query`. La función que está usando el OP ha sido dada como respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967), en la cual se abordaba precisamente esa dificultad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código que estás usando es un sucedáneo de `fetch_assoc` al cual se debe recurrir cuando:

- usas consultas preparadas
- y quieres guardar tus resultados en un array asociativo
- y no quieres usar el engorroso `bind_result` en  el caso de tener muchas columnas o porque no quieres usarlo y punto
- y no tienes instalado el driver `mysqlnd`

Entonces, la función `myGetResult`<sup><kbd>1</kbd></sup> haría el trabajo que debería hacer `get_result` cuando existe `mysqlnd`. Lo que tienes que hacer es simplemente, pasar el `$stmt` a `myGetResult`, la cual te devolverá una arreglo asociativo que podrás usar como quieras o agregarlo a la variable de sesión.

Veamos:

```
$email=(empty($_POST['email']))    ? NULL : $_POST['email'];
$pwd  =(empty($_POST['password'])) ? NULL : $_POST['password'];

if ($email && $pwd && $conn){
    $sql='SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE email=? AND password=?';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$pwd);
        $stmt->execute();
            $arrDatos=myGetResult ($stmt);
            $_SESSION['usuario']=$arrDatos;
            var_dump($_SESSION['usuario']);
            /*Estas dos líneas no pueden ir después de la redirección*/
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();

            /*Descomenta la línea que sigue luego de probar la variable de sesión*/
            //header('Location: consola.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No se encontraron registros";
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error en la consulta: ".$stmt->error;
    }   
}
else
{
    echo "Falta alguno de los datos del POST o la conexión es nula";
}



function myGetResult( $Statement ) {
    $RESULT = array();
    $Statement->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
        $PARAMS = array();
        while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
        $Statement->fetch();
    }
    return $RESULT;
}
```

---

<sup><kbd>1</kbd></sup> La función fue dada como solución al problema planteado en la pregunta: [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967)

Comment: como los resultados de cada columna?

Comment: @ger no entiendo tu comentario ...

Comment: es decir el email individual y el nombre indivual en una variable o algo así

Comment: Lo que hace `fetch_assoc` es devolverte un arreglo asociativo de todos los resultados obtenidos en la consulta (puede ser una fila, dos, tres... las que haya) y por cada fila un arreglo con cada clave/valor de las columnas del `SELECT`. Por ejemplo si era un `SELECT email, nombre FROM ...` el resultado sería algo así: `array(array("email"=>"fulano@mail.com", "nombre"=>"fulano"))`... y si fueran varias filas, algo así: `array(array("email"=>"fulano1@mail.com", "nombre"=>"fulano1"), array("email"=>"fulano2@mail.com", "nombre"=>"fulano2"))`. Ese array se puede leer con un `foreach` o pasarlo

Comment: es decir lo puedo hacer así `$_SESSION['usuario']['email']`

Comment: como imprimo solo email

Comment: @ger ese dependerá de cómo quede tu variable de sesión. Por eso te puse un `var_dump`, para que revises su estructura y entonces sepas cómo tienes que leerla. Es posible que te quede un array anidado que podrías leer con algo parecido a esto: `foreach ($_SESSION['usuario'] as $k=>$v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        foreach ($v as $row){
            echo $row["email"].PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79141/discussion-between-ger-and-a-cedano).