# No muestra todos los datos de la BD mysql en mi tabla

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hola que tal,

Vengo con una duda del porque no me muestra los datos de mi base de datos mysql en una tabla que cree en mi html. Se salta el primer usuario, cabe mencionar que ya revise mi conexión, el nombre de los campos a detalle y los links.

Actualmente tengo esto así:

```
<?php
session_start();

require'funcs/conexion.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
}
?> 

<?php

$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, costo, horario, acercade, edad, sexo, servicios, usuario_municipio FROM usuarios"; 

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $row = mi_fetchassoc($stmt);
}
// $stmt->free_result();

$mysqli->close();

function mi_fetchassoc($stmt)
{
    if ($stmt->num_rows>0)
    {
        $rs = array();
        $md = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $params = array();
        while($field = $md->fetch_field()) {
            $params[] = &$rs[$field->name];
        }

        call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params);

        if($stmt->fetch())
            return $rs;
    }
    return null;
}
?>



<html>
    <head>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">  

    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="container">
        <div class="row table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>

                            <th>Nombre</th>   
                            <th>Costo</th>
                            <th>Horario</th>
                            <th>Edad</th>
                            <th>Sexo</th>
                            <th>Servicios</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                    <?php while($row = mi_fetchassoc($stmt))
                        { ?>
                    <tr>

                        <td><?php echo $row['nombre']; ?></td>   
                        <td><?php echo $row['costo']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['horario']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['edad']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['sexo']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['servicios']; ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>

                    </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </tbody>                    

                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Pero no me muestra el primer usuario registrado solo los demás ¿porque sera este problema?  perdón por el desorden en el código aun no se como ordenar el código.

Espero que alguien pueda orientarme

Saludos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que te estás *comiendo* el primer registro una vez ejecutas la consulta, aquí:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $row = mi_fetchassoc($stmt); // <== Aquí
}
```

De manera que cuando llegas aquí:

```
            <tbody>
            <?php while($row = mi_fetchassoc($stmt))
                { ?>
            <tr>
```

ya empiezas desde el segundo registro.

Prueba simplemente quitado el fetch (mi_fetchassoc) que hay después del execute. No necesitas un fetch en ese momento. El código posterior debería ser el encargado de hacer los fetch.

Comment: Gracias estimado tenias razón, ya quedo, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Como complemente a la respuesta de @Julio, y porque parte de tu código me parece familiar, debo decir que `mi_fetchassoc` fue en un pasado no muy lejano una función que había inventado para almacenar en un array el conjunto de resultados **cuando se usaban consultas preparadas y no se tenía instalado el driver `mysqlnd`.**

El caso fue expuesto aquí con toda amplitud: [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967) y ahí podemos ver en efecto la función `mi_fetchassoc`.  [La respuesta de @DBulten es óptima **para esos casos** y es la que recomiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114105/29967). Si decides usarla, solamente bastaría con recuperar en una variable lo que te devolverá la función `Arreglo_Get_Result` de la respuesta ya mencionada.

Por ejemplo:

```
$resultado= Arreglo_Get_Result($stmt);
```

En `$resultado` tienes tu array y sólo lo lees o lo pasas a donde quieras sin necesidad de más manipulaciones.

[Aquí hay un ejemplo completo funcionando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/132176/29967).

En resumen, si te decides por esta función, el código quedaría así:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, costo, horario, acercade, edad, sexo, servicios, usuario_municipio FROM usuarios"; 
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
if($stmt){
    $stmt->execute();
    /*Tendrás los resultados en $arrDatos sin necesidad de ninguna otra manipulación*/
    $arrDatos=myGetResult($stmt);
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();

/*
    * FUNCION QUE EMULA EL FETCH_ASSOC DE PDO
    * Esta función nos permite crear un array asociativo con los resultados
    * Así accedemos fácimente a su valor por el nombre de columna en la base de datos
    * Es particularmente útil cuando en el SELECT tenemos muchas columnas
    * porque de lo contrario, tendríamos que hacer un bind de cada columna a mano
    * Esta función se puede incorporar a una clase utilitaria, para re-usarla en
    * todas las consultas que requieran este tipo de operaciones
*/

function myGetResult( $Statement ) {
    $RESULT = array();
    $Statement->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
        $PARAMS = array();
        while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
        $Statement->fetch();
    }
    return $RESULT;
}
```

### Pero... ¿realmente necesitas una consulta preparada en este caso?

La consulta: `SELECT id, nombre, costo, horario, acercade, edad, sexo, servicios, usuario_municipio FROM usuarios` no comporta ningún riesgo de inyección SQL, por lo que la puedes ejecutar sin ningún problema mediante el método `query` simplemente. De ese modo te ahorras:

- Prepararla
- Ejecutarla
- Enfrentar la dificultad de mysqli para almacenar resultados de consultas preparadas antes explicada

En ese caso, la obtención de un array asociativo es más simple, de este modo:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, costo, horario, acercade, edad, sexo, servicios, usuario_municipio FROM usuarios"; 
$datos = $mysqli->query($sql);
if($datos->num_rows > 0) {
    $arrDatos=array();
    while ($row = $datos->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $arrDatos[]=$row;
    }
}
 /*Aquí puedes disponer de $arrDatos que será un arreglo asociativo con los resultados*/
 /*Cerrar recursos*/
```

Comment: Yo creo que es buena política utilizar prepared statements por todo. Quizás en un futuro se hace un cambio inocente agregando un filtro y ya tienes una posible inyección sql. Obviamente también te podría pasar con prepared statements si no te molestas en bindear el dato nuevo, pero sería más difícil olvidarse. Otra posible ventaja, si no recuerdo mal, es que se podría volver a repetir la query y las siguientes veces serían algo más rápidas ya que ya que la SQL ya habría sido 'precompilada'

Comment: @A. Cedano efectivamente tenia ese mismo problema al imprimir los datos de una consulta preparada, así que estuve un tiempo buscando como hacerlo, de hecho me preguntaba si era necesario poner mi query en una consulta preparada o no, por lo que igual decidí hacerlo de este modo, es grato saber que los demás se toman su tiempo para dar explicaciones a detalle, de este modo uno aprende mas sobre como trabajar. Saludos.