# Error en mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando desarrolla una función que me ayude a simplificar mis consultas a la base de datos. La estoy implementando con consultas preparadas y un poco de dinamismo al momento de saber que estoy ejecutando. La verdad nunca he utilizado las consultas preparadas ni tampoco he utilizado `mysqli` por objetos (Siempre lo he hecho por procedimientos, por ejemplo `mysqli_query()` ) El código ya lo documenté entonces no creo que haya tanto problema en explicar que hace. Tengo un problema que dice lo siguiente

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc() in
>   /fakepath/QueryEngine.php:80

Reitero, nunca he usado este procedimiento, a ustedes les puede parecer algo obvio el error.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
class QueryEngine {

  protected $conn;
  public function __construct(){
    $server     = 'localjost';
    $user       = 'iuser';
    $pass       = 'pasuord';
    $db         = 'deirabeis';
    $this->conn = new mysqli( $server, $user, $pass, $db );
  }

  public function executeQuery( $query, $params, $type, $meta = false ){
    //Preparamos dos arreglos que servirán para retornar y almacenar parametros
    $result    = array();
    $data      = array();
    //Separamos la consulta y los tipos de datos que se enviaran
    $order_arr = explode( ' ', $query );
    $type_arr  = explode( ',', $type  );
    //La orden será la primera detección (select, update, insert)
    $order     = strtolower( $order_arr[0] );
    //Validamos si hay errores en la conexión y creamos un arreglo asociativo
    //Si está la meta activa se añade información extra
    if( $this->conn->connect_errno ){
      $result['data']    = null;
      $result['message'] = "Falló la conexión a la base de datos";
      if( $meta ){
          $result['meta']['query']  = $query;
          $result['meta']['params'] = implode( ',', $params );
          $result['meta']['error']  = $this->conn->connect_errno . ' ' . '('.$this->conn->connect_error.')';
      }

    }

    else{
      //Añadimos la codificación de los datos
      $this->conn->set_charset( 'utf-8' );
      //Validamos que se haya preparado bien la consulta y creamos el arreglo
      if( !$stmt = $this->conn->prepare( $query ) ){
        $result['data']    = null;
        $result['message'] = "Consulta mal formada";
        if( $meta ){
            $result['meta']['query']  = $query;
            $result['meta']['params'] = implode( ',', $params );
            $result['meta']['error']  =  $this->conn->errno . " " . $this->conn->error;
        }
      }

      else{
        //Ciclamos los parámetros, los limpiamos y los agregamos al arreglo $data
        foreach( $params as $param ){
          array_push( $data, $this->conn->real_escape_string($param) );
        }
        //Ligamos los parámetros y su respectivo tipo de dato al statement
        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $data ); $i++ ) {
            $stmt->bind_param( $type_arr[ $i ], $data[ $i ] );
        }
        //Validamos la ejecución de la consulta
        if( !$stmt->execute() ){
          $result['data']    = null;
          $result['message'] = "Consulta mal formada";
          if( $meta ){
              $result['meta']['query']  = $query;
              $result['meta']['params'] = implode( ',', $params );
              $result['meta']['error']  =  $this->conn->errno . " " . $this->conn->error;
          }
        }

        else{
          //Según cual sea la sentencia se ejecutarán diferentes acciones
          switch ( $order ) {
            case 'select':
              //Almacenamos la información
              $stmt->store_result();
              $x = 0;
              //Barremos los resultados
              while ( $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc() ) {
                  $data[ $x ] = $row;
                $x++;
              }

              $result['data']    = $data;
              $result['message'] = "Consulta exitosa";
              if( $meta ){
                  $result['meta']['query']  = $query;
                  $result['meta']['params'] = implode( ',', $params );
                  $result['meta']['error']  = 'No error';
              }
              //Liberamos la memoria
              $stmt->free_result();
            break;

            case 'insert':
            break;

            case 'update':
            break;


            default:
              $result['data']    = null;
              $result['message'] = "No es posible ejecutar esta acción";
              if( $meta ){
                  $result['meta']['query']  = $query;
                  $result['meta']['params'] = implode( ',', $params );
                  $result['meta']['error']  = 'Sentencia ' . $oder . ' no reconocida';
              }
            break;
          }
        }
        //Cerramos la conexión
        $stmt->close();
      }
    }
    //Retornamos el resultado
    return $result;
  }
}
?>
```

Estoy invocando el método de la siguiente forma:

```
include 'QueryEngine.php';
$queryBuilder = new QueryEngine();

$query  = "SELECT * FROM USERS";
$params = array();
$values = '';

$result = $queryBuilder->executeQuery( $query, $params, $values, 1 );

print_r( $result );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alberto el error no es tan *tonto*  como podrías creer, y es fruto de una de las mayores dificultades que tiene (a mi juicio) la API `mysqli`: **la dificultad de obtener un arreglo asociativo de resultados cuando usamos consultas preparadas**.

Lo voy a explicar con la documentación.

Si observas el Manual de PHP, verás que **[`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)** es un método aplicable al objeto:  [**`mysqli_result`**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-result.php).  **¿Por qué te dice *`Call to undefined method`*?** Por una razón muy simple: **¡Las consultas preparadas no devuelven objetos `mysqli_result`!** Aquí, `while ( $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc() ) {`  tú aplicas el método `fetch_assoc()` a un objeto `$stmt` que no dispone de ese método (ver aquí los métodos de que dispone el objeto [**`mysqli_stmt`**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-stmt.php)). Si estuvieras usando `query`, que sí devuelve objetos `mysqli_result` no tendrías ese problema. Pero `query` no te conviene, porque necesitas dar seguridad a tu código y para ello es obligatorio usar consultas preparadas.

**¿Qué devuelve entonces una consulta preparada?**

Para que nos entendamos, con una consulta preparada no ocurre como con `query` la cual devuelve por sí misma un resultado al ejecutarse directamente. La consulta preparada hay que:

- prepararla `prepare`
- ejecutarla `execute`
- obtener un conjunto de resultados luego de la ejecución con un método adecuado que no es precisamente `fetch_assoc` . Lo dice el Manual de PHP al explicar el método [**`execute()`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.execute.php):

> #### Nota:
>
> Al usar `mysqli_stmt_execute()`, se debe usar la función `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` para obtener los datos antes de realizar
>   cualquier consulta adicional.

Es decir, para obtener los datos, **hay que usar el método `fetch`**. Vamos a revisar ese método en el Manual de PHP:

Lo primero que vemos es que el método se define así:

**`mysqli_stmt::fetch`**  O sea, es un método aplicable a `mysqli_stmt`, que es el objeto con el que trabajamos en consultas preparadas. Luego, leemos su definición, la cual (podría) complicarnos la existencia. Veamos:

> Obtiene los resultados de una sentencia preparadas en las variables
>   vinculadas

La cuestión incómoda en la definición es el final: *las variables vinculadas*. O sea, que en un `SELECT` con 15, 20, 40 columnas, **deberías vincular igual cantidad de variables para obtener los resultados**, usando el método `bind_result`. Por ejemplo:

```
$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col_n);
$arrDatos=array();
/* obtener los valores */
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $arrDatos[]=array("col1"=>$col1, "col2"=>$col2, "col_n"=>$col_n);
}
```

Esta sería una forma (algo engorrosa, aún con pocas columnas, ¡imagina si son muchas!) de obtener un arreglo asociativo de resultados cuando usamos consultas preparadas.

---

### ¿No hay alternativa?

Sí. Hay dos (o tres) alternativas.

#### 1ª Alternativa: puedes usar [`get_result`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

`get_result`  sí es aplicable a objetos `mysqli_stmt`. Pero este método depende de si tienes instalado o no el driver `mysqlnd`. Este driver no viene instalado en todos los sistemas y podrías entonces estar produciendo un código que funcionaría en unos escenarios y en otros no.

Si lo quieres implementar, sería así:

```
   $stmt->execute();
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   $arrDatos=array();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $arrDatos[]=$row;
   }
```

¡Super sencillo, sin tener que escribir a mano los nombres de columna!

#### 2ª Alternativa: puedes usar tu propia función que emule a `get_result`

El problema que estás enfrentando yo lo percibí hace un tiempo, por lo que plantee esta pregunta para encontrar una solución a casos como estos: [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967)

Nuestro amigo [@D.Bulten respondió con una función que hace el trabajo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114105/29967):

```
function my_get_result( $Statement ) {
    $RESULT = array();
    $Statement->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $Statement->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $Metadata = $Statement->result_metadata();
        $PARAMS = array();
        while ( $Field = $Metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $PARAMS[] = &$RESULT[ $i ][ $Field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $Statement, 'bind_result' ), $PARAMS );
        $Statement->fetch();
    }
    return $RESULT;
}
```

El uso sería muy sencillo. Sería pasarle el objeto `$stmt` a la función, ella organiza un arreglo asociativo y te devuelve dicho arreglo:

```
   $stmt->execute();
   $arrDatos=my_get_result($stmt);
```

Esta función se podría incorporar en tu programa a una `clase` utilitaria, que mantendrá tu código independiente de drivers que podrían estar o no instalados en ciertos entornos.

Si quieres ver la aplicación de la función **en un contexto completo de consultas preparadas y manejo de datos**, [puedes ver esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132156/c%C3%B3mo-aseguro-mi-conexi%C3%B3n-de-php-a-mysql/132176#132176).

#### 3ª Alternativa

Puedes usar `PDO`, que no te hará dar tantas vueltas para obtener resultados cuando usas consultas preparadas.

Comment: Estuvo perfecto este post Cedano. Afortunadamente si tenía instalado mysqlnd. Gracias por tu ayuda, ya funcionó.