# Múltiples bind_param() está fallando

Tags: php

Estoy optimizando unas consultas preparadas, sin embargo estoy atorado en el método `bind_param()` y la condición `WHERE del SQL`. Quiero hacer un `for` y dentro invocar este método con su respectiva información, el código completo está en esta liga [Consultas preparadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/204511/error-en-mysqli-stmtfetch-assoc/204588#204588). La formule hace un par de días y ya me ayudaron sin embargo ahora estoy con este problema.

```
$query    = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME LIKE ? AND STATUS = ?";
$type_arr = array( 's','i' );
$data     = array('%Alberto%', 1);
$stmt     = $conn->prepare( $query );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $data ); $i++ ) {
  $stmt->bind_param( $type_arr[ $i ], $data[ $i ] );
}

$stmt->execute();
```

Me ocurre el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match
> number of parameters in prepared statement in file.php on line 59

Si lo hago solo con un parámetro si me trae la información. Cómo puedo hacer para poder incluir esta información por medio de arreglos?

Comment: es onda query builder?

Comment: Intenta colocar en el query `SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME LIKE :name AND STATUS = :status`
y luego maneja los bind_param, individual

Comment: Ehm, no se que es query builder Malbarez. Asdrubal, no puedo manejarlos separados, vaya no quiero reclarar variables, quiero que todo sea "automático"

Comment: query builder es cuando armas (build) la consulta (query) dinámicamente, en este caso si el `select` no cambia el bind es `bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )` osea los type es una cadena `"si"` (String Integer) y los valores de los parámetros es una lista de variables separadas por comas, misma cantidad de letras que de variables separadas por comas (y mismo tipo)

Comment: o sea bindeas todo junto, por eso el error. si bindeas de a uno dice que no le cierra la cantidad de `?` con las cosas que le pasas

Comment: Entonces no se puede lo que yo estoy intentando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hace tiempo me encontré con un problema similar, la solución que encontré para el caso expuesto sería similar a esto.

Usa la función *call_user_func_array* para pasar los parámetros a *bind_param*.

```
$query    = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE NAME LIKE ? AND STATUS = ?";
$type_arr = array( 's','i' );
$data     = array('%Alberto%', 1);
$stmt     = $conn->prepare( $query );

$type  ='';
$params=array();
for($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    $type.=$type_arr[$i];
}

// para call_user_func_array, los parámetros del array
// se deben pasar por referencia
$params[]= &$type;

for($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
    // para call_user_func_array, los parámetros del array
    // se deben pasar por referencia
    $params[]= &$data[$i];
}

call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);

$stmt->execute();
```

Esto solucionaba el error `Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement` y retornaba datos de la consulta.

Comment: Gracias por el truco sensei