# Usar un Array en Sentencias Preparadas usando MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statements

Yo uso una clase para ejecutar todas las querys de mis sistemas, funciona así:

Un archivo de **Querys** contiene las sentencias y manda llamar a la función `queryFunction` de mi clase **dbm**. Está clase ejecuta todas las sentencias SQL, hace los fetch, num_rows, last_id, whiles, contadores y todo lo relacionado.

```
public function getUser($sanedUser){
    $sql = "SELECT id, user, email... FROM user WHERE user = '$sanedUser' OR email = '$sanedUser' ";

    $result = $this->dbm->queryFunction($sql);
    $usuario = $this->dbm->whileFunction($result);
    if ($this->dbm->numRowsFunction($result) > 0) {
        return $usuario;
    }
}
```

Todo funciona bien. Pero ahora quiero cambiar a Prepared Statements y lo estoy implementando de la siguiente forma

```
public function getUser($sanedUser){
    $sql = "SELECT id, user, email... FROM user WHERE user = ? OR email = ? ";
    $paramsType = 'ss';
    $params = [$sanedUser, $sanedUser];


    $result = $this->dbm->queryFunction($sql, $paramsType, $params);
    $usuario = $this->dbm->whileFunction($result);
    if ($this->dbm->numRowsFunction($result) > 0) {
        return $usuario;
    }
}
```

En el archivo **DBM** en la `queryFunction` tengo lo siguiente. Comento el resultado de los `echo`

```
public function queryFunction($sql, $paramsType, $params){
    $MySQLi = $this->mysqli;
    $sql = trim($sql);

    try {
        echo '<br>'.$sql; // SELECT id, user, email...
        echo '<br>'.$paramsType; // ss
        echo '<br>'.$parameters = implode(", ", $params); // admin, admin

        $stmt = $MySQLi->prepare($sql);
        
        $stmt->bind_param($paramsType, $parameters); // De esta forma me da el error
        
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $paramsType, $params); // De esta forma también, pasando el array puro
        $stmt->execute();

        $result_set = $stmt->get_result();
        $lastID = $MySQLi->insert_id;

        // return $result_set;
        return array($result_set, $lastID);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Debugger
            echo '<br>'.$e->getMessage();
        return '';
        die();
    }
}
```

El problema es que aunque en los `echo` dice que los tipos son **ss** y que los parámetros son **admin, admin** (parámetros de ejemplo), siempre me da el error **uncaught argument error the number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement**.

He leído la [documentación de PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230937/8691961) y pone que se puede hacer de las dos formas que les muestro, igual he leído [este post de SOes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178926/prepared-statements-with-an-array) y lo tengo bien.

Lo único que he visto es que en la mayoría de ejemplos, los parámetros son variables algo como `bind_param($paramsType, $name, $email);` pero yo no puedo hacer eso ya que debo hacerlo todo en una sola función, y esa función debe servir para ejecutar todas las querys (SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) que se presenten.

También he leído este [otro post de SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/341833/problemas-con-array-en-sentencia-preparada) y lo que hacen es un `bindParam` para cada elemento del array con un `foreach`. Se supone (porque no hay respuesta aceptada) que de esa forma funcionó, pero a parte de ser con PDO el ejemplo, yo no quisiera hacer un `foreach` para cada elemento del array ya que la documentación no lo muestra así.

Alguna idea de como puedo llegar a mi meta usando el menor código posible??

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Múltiples bind\_param() está fallando](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/205977/m%c3%baltiples-bind-param-est%c3%a1-fallando)

Comment: Aplicado a tu código sería: `call_user_func_array(array($stmt, "bind_param"), array_merge(array($paramsType), $params));`

Comment: Tambien te puede servir [esta otra solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383870/16597)

Comment: @Marcos voy a revisarlas en un rato, aunque he visto que en su mayoría lo hacen con un ciclo (algo que no es malo) y lo menciono en el post, pero la documentación dice que se puede hacer sin ciclos. Pero si resuelvo de esta manera aceptaré lo de la pregunta similar que me han planteado en el post. Muchas Gracias...

Comment: si vas a optar por utilizar un ciclo recorrer los `$params`, entonces te podes ahorrar indicar el `$paramsType`; mientras iteras los `$params` podes verificar el tipo de valor e ir armando la variable de `$types`.

Comment: @Marcos, he aceptado la respuesta de Arkanis puesto me ha resuelto de forma más optima y ordenada mi duda. Es apreciación personal. Pero he tomado muy en cuanta su ultimo comment y ya tengo todo con querys preparadas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***AS-IS*** no tuve tiempo de validar el código php, tienes que adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Como lo indica Marcos más o menos deberías de hacerlo así:

```
public function queryFunction($sql, $paramsType, $params){
    $MySQLi = $this->mysqli;
    $sql = trim($sql);

    try {
        echo '<br>'.$sql; // Verificamos la consulta SQL
        echo '<br>'.$paramsType; // Verificamos los tipos de parámetros

        // Crear un array de referencias para los parámetros
        $bindParams = array($paramsType);
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $bindParams[] = &$params[$key];
        }

        // Usar call_user_func_array para enlazar los parámetros
        call_user_func_array(array($MySQLi, 'bind_param'), $bindParams);

        // Preparar y ejecutar la consulta
        $stmt = $MySQLi->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result_set = $stmt->get_result();
        $lastID = $MySQLi->insert_id;

        // Devolver el conjunto de resultados y el último ID
        return array($result_set, $lastID);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Manejar excepciones
        echo '<br>'.$e->getMessage();
        return '';
    }
}
```

Entonces, se debe implementar `call_user_func_array` para enlazar estos parámetros en la función `bind_param` de `MySQLi`, sigo pensando que prefiero usar PDO.

```
public function queryFunction($sql, $params){
    $pdo = $this->pdo; // $pdo es una instancia de PDO previamente configurada
    $sql = trim($sql);

    try {
        echo '<br>'.$sql; // Verificamos la consulta SQL

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        
        // Enlazamos los parámetros utilizando bindValue
        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            $stmt->bindValue($key + 1, $value);
        }

        $stmt->execute();

        $result_set = $stmt->fetchAll(); // Obtener todos los resultados
        $lastID = $pdo->lastInsertId();

        // Devolver el conjunto de resultados y el último ID
        return array($result_set, $lastID);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Manejar excepciones de PDO
        echo '<br>'.$e->getMessage();
        return '';
    }
}
```

voy a estar pronto subiendo a github una libreria para manejo de bases de datos si estas interesada me lo haces saber y te aviso cuando lo haga.

Comment: Voy a probar y si toca hacer un ciclo así lo haré. Sí tengo interés, me avisa por favor. Y también voy a ver si lo migro a PDO de una tal cual lo hemos discutido en el chat.

Answer (score 1):

### Si el tipo de dato no es importante

[A partir de PHP 8.1](https://php.watch/versions/8.1/mysqli_stmt_execute-params) es posible pasar los valores al método `execute()` de `mysqli` mediante un array, tal y como se hace con `PDO`. [Esta es la propuesta](https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/6271) que fue aprobada en abril del 2021, y disponible desde PHP 8.1.

Esto simplifica el código enormemente, pudiendo hacer algo como:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, user, email FROM user WHERE user = ? OR email = ?";
$params = array($sanedUser, $sanedUser);
$stmt = $MySQLi->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Simplemente la consulta se pasa con los marcadores `?` y los datos a vincular se pasan como un array al método `execute()`.

Esto permite otras ventajas, como vincular un array a una lista de datos a insertar, o en consultas del tipo `IN()`, etc.

Veamos varios ejemplos de esta nueva posibilidad, sabiendo que se pueden ampliar a otros usos.

Dejo todo en un bloque de código y [un fiddle que incluye base de datos, para que lo puedas ver funcionando y hacer pruebas](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/c746c8b9d877274763515260dac3bc8f/php/php81/b0361447f975d5aecaa8bd8319106d72/). Los bloques de código son:

- El caso planteado en la pregunta original
- Un `INSERT` simple donde se vincular sólo los valores, teniendo éste las columnas predefinidas
- Un `INSERT` donde se recogen por un lado las columnas y por otro los valores. Para este caso, en los parámetros debe haber un array asociativo. Este estilo sería el idóneo si interesa manejar los tipos de datos (luego puedo aportar un ejemplo si te interesa).
- Un `SELECT` pasando un array para los parámetros del `IN()`
- Finalmente una prueba de todos los datos.

#### Código

```
<?php
    
    echo "Ejemplo inicial",PHP_EOL;
    $sql = "SELECT id, user, email FROM user WHERE user = ? OR email = ?";
    $params = array('Yenn','yenn@mail.com');
    $marks=str_repeat('?,', count($params) - 1) . '?';
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    $rs = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
        print_r($row);
    }
    
    #INSERT simple
    $params = array('Pedro','pedro@mail.com');
    $marks=str_repeat('?,', count($params) - 1) . '?';
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `user` (`user`,`email`) VALUES (%s)",$marks);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    printf("%sINSERT simple -> Filas insertadas: %d %s %s",PHP_EOL,$mysqli->affected_rows,PHP_EOL,PHP_EOL);
    
    #INSERT con columnas dinámicas
    $params = array('user'=>'Lidia','email'=>'lidia@mail.com');
    $marks=str_repeat('?,', count($params) - 1) . '?';
    # Es buena práctica poner `  en los nombres de tablas / columnas
    $columns=sprintf("%s%s%s",'`',implode('`,`',array_keys($params)),'`');
    $values=array_values($params);
    $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `user` (%s) VALUES (%s)",$columns,$marks);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    #OJO: En este caso pasamos $values
    $stmt->execute($values);
    printf("INSERT con columnas dinámicas -> Filas insertadas: %d %s",$mysqli->affected_rows,PHP_EOL);
    
    #Prueba del tipo IN
    echo PHP_EOL,"Resultados prueba con IN()",PHP_EOL;
    $params = array(1,3,5);
    $marks=str_repeat('?,', count($params) - 1) . '?';
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT id, user, email FROM user WHERE id IN(%s)",$marks);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    $rs = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
        print_r($row);
    }
    
    #Verificar todos los datos
    echo PHP_EOL,"Resultados generales",PHP_EOL;
    $sql = "SELECT `id`, `user`, `email` FROM `user`";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rs = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
        print_r($row);
    }
```

#### Salida

```
Ejemplo inicial
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [user] => Yenn
    [email] => yenn@mail.com
)

INSERT simple -> Filas insertadas: 1 
 
INSERT con columnas dinámicas -> Filas insertadas: 1 

Resultados prueba con IN()
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [user] => Yenn
    [email] => yenn@mail.com
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [user] => José
    [email] => jose@mail.com
)
Array
(
    [id] => 5
    [user] => Lidia
    [email] => lidia@mail.com
)

Resultados generales
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [user] => Yenn
    [email] => yenn@mail.com
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [user] => Marta
    [email] => marta@mail.com
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [user] => José
    [email] => jose@mail.com
)
Array
(
    [id] => 4
    [user] => Pedro
    [email] => pedro@mail.com
)
Array
(
    [id] => 5
    [user] => Lidia
    [email] => lidia@mail.com
)
```

### Si el tipo de dato es importante

Lo puedes garantizar sea pasándolo explícitamente en forma de cadena o creándolo de algún modo.

Considerando que desde PHP 5.6+ puedes pasar a `bind_param` los tipos como una cadena y los valores como un array usando el operador `...`, sería tan simple como esto:

```
$stmt->bind_param($tipos, ...$arrayDeDatos);
```

Pensando en reutilizar código, puedes crear una función como esta, [la podrás ver funcionando en un escenario que incluye base de datos](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/04b9fca48a8c94ab965d2e03353bcd03/php/php81/1fc97ff6b008a360151d2e1b8443f980/):

```
function prepareInsert($table,$data,$types){
    $columns = sprintf("(%s%s%s)",'`',implode('`,`', array_keys($data)),'`');
    $marks = str_repeat('?,', count($data) - 1) . '?';
    $sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO `$table` %s VALUES(%s)",$columns,$marks);
    $values=implode('',array_values($types));
    $safeTypes="";
    foreach (array_keys($data) as $k){
        $safeTypes.=$types[$k]??""; 
    }
    return array('sql'=>$sql,'safeTypes'=>$safeTypes);
}
```

La misma va a recibir tres parámetros:

- El nombre de la tabla
- Los datos, organizados en un array asociativo de `columna=>valor`
- Los tipos de cada columna.

Esta función se podrá usar **para preparar un `INSERT` de cualquier tabla**, a condición de que le pases los datos correctos, claro está. Lo tipos se vincularán correctamente, sin importar el orden en que estén los datos (como se podrá ver en el fiddle), **porque no se usa el orden**, sino los nombres asociativos. Esto evitará eventuales errores.

#### Código de ejemplo

```
<?php

    $userTypes=array(
        'user'=>'s',
        'email'=>'s',
        'cityId'=>'i'
    );
    
    $cityTypes=array(
        'name'=>'s',
        'countryId'=>'i'
    );
    
    $data = array(
        'user'=>'Lidia',
        'email'=>'lidia@mail.com', 
        'cityId'=>3,
    );
    
    $params=prepareInsert('user',$data,$userTypes);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($params['sql']);
    $stmt->bind_param($params['safeTypes'], ...array_values($data));
    $stmt->execute();
    printf("%sFilas insertadas: %d %s %s",PHP_EOL,$mysqli->affected_rows,PHP_EOL,PHP_EOL);
    
    #Prueba con datos en otro orden (cityId antes que email)
    $data = array(
        'user'=>'Claudio',
        'cityId'=>7,
        'email'=>'claudio@mail.com', 
    );
    
    $params=prepareInsert('user',$data,$userTypes);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($params['sql']);
    $stmt->bind_param($params['safeTypes'], ...array_values($data));
    $stmt->execute();
    printf("%sFilas insertadas: %d %s %s",PHP_EOL,$mysqli->affected_rows,PHP_EOL,PHP_EOL);
    
    #Prueba con otra tabla
    
    $data = array(
        'name'=>'Madrid',
        'countryId'=>4,
    );
    
    $params=prepareInsert('city',$data,$cityTypes);
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($params['sql']);
    $stmt->bind_param($params['safeTypes'], ...array_values($data));
    $stmt->execute();
    printf("%sFilas insertadas: %d %s %s",PHP_EOL,$mysqli->affected_rows,PHP_EOL,PHP_EOL);
    
    echo PHP_EOL,"Datos en user",PHP_EOL;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rs = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
        print_r($row);
    }
    
    echo PHP_EOL,"Datos en city",PHP_EOL;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM city";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rs = $stmt->get_result();
    while($row=$rs->fetch_assoc()){
        print_r($row);
    }
    
    
    function prepareInsert($table,$data,$types){
        $columns = sprintf("(%s%s%s)",'`',implode('`,`', array_keys($data)),'`');
        $marks = str_repeat('?,', count($data) - 1) . '?';
        $sql=sprintf("INSERT INTO `$table` %s VALUES(%s)",$columns,$marks);
        $values=implode('',array_values($types));
        $safeTypes="";
        foreach (array_keys($data) as $k){
            $safeTypes.=$types[$k]??""; 
        }
        return array('sql'=>$sql,'safeTypes'=>$safeTypes);
    }
```

#### Salida

```
Filas insertadas: 1 
 

Filas insertadas: 1 
 

Filas insertadas: 1 
 

Datos en user
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [user] => Yenn
    [email] => yenn@mail.com
    [cityId] => 8
)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [user] => Lidia
    [email] => lidia@mail.com
    [cityId] => 3
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [user] => Claudio
    [email] => claudio@mail.com
    [cityId] => 7
)

Datos en city
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Madrid
    [countryId] => 4
)
```

Comment: A. Cedano, en varios de sus ejemplos no veo el tipo de datos (`ssi`) ?? Porque yo probé con le primera forma y no me funcionó, habré hecho algo malo...

Comment: @Yenn ¿da algún error o simplemente no arroja datos? Si da error, indícame cuál es. En cuanto al tipo de datos, en casi todos los escenarios pasaría con el tipo de datos por defecto, que es `s`. Si especificar el tipo de dato es obligatorio, entonces sí habría que implementar una estrategia que especifique el tipo de dato. En ese caso, se puede usar `...` en vez de `call_user_func_array` a no ser que estés trabajando en una versión muy antigua de PHP.

Comment: @Yenn me equivoqué al hacer el `implode` de los parámetros, omití un backstick antes de la coma, lo cual resultaba en una consulta SQL errónea. No me di cuenta al no probarlo en un escenario real. Si corriges así: **``$columns=sprintf("%s%s%s",'`',implode('`,`',array_keys($params)),'`');``** debería funcionar. He editado agregando datos de prueba.

Comment: Gracias, voy a tenerlo muy en cuenta. Muy amable A. Cedano (su nick no se puede llamar con @ )

Comment: @Yenn No sé si es `@acedano` o `@a.cedano`, no puedo comprobarlo, dado que no me puedo llamar a mí mismo. Pero no funciona aquí porque no hace falta mencionar al autor de la respuesta, el mismo es notificado de todos los comentarios de su respuesta.

Comment: aaaaaa eso puede ser, que usted es el autor de la respuesta. Gracias