# PHP - No me funciona el fetch_all (MYSQLI_ASSOC)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in C:\MAMP\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\index.php:76 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\index.php on line 76

getMessage();
                            }
                        ?>

```
                    <?php $conn->multi_query($sql); ?>

                    <?php
                        do {
                          $resultado = $conn->store_result();
                          $row = $resultado->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); ?>

                          <?php $i = 0; ?>
                          <?php foreach ($row as $evento): ?>
                              <?php if($i % 2 == 0) { ?>
                                <div id="<?php echo strtolower($evento['cat_evento']) ?>" class="info-curso ocultar clearfix">
                              <?php } ?>
                                      <div class="detalle-evento">
                                          <h3><?php echo utf8_encode($evento['nombre_evento']) ?></h3>
                                          <p><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $evento['hora_evento']; ?></p>
                                          <p><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $evento['fecha_evento']; ?></p>
                                          <p><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo $evento['nombre_evento']; ?></p>
                                      </div>

                                      <a href="#" class="button float-right">Ver todos</a>
                              <?php if($i % 2 == 1): ?>
                                </div> <!--#talleres-->
                              <?php endif; ?>
                          <?php $i++; ?>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                        <?php $resultado->free(); ?>
                      <?php } while ($conn->more_results() && $conn->next_result()); ?>
```

Comment: En el [Manual de PHP sobre `fetch_all`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) se dice que esta función solo está disponible con el drive `mysqlnd`. El *undefined method* que estás recibiendo puede ser un claro indicativo de que dicho drive no está instalado en tu entorno. No sé por qué los creadores de `mysqli` optaron por hacer depender ciertos métodos de drives externos, lo cierto es que esto es un grave escollo para los desarrolladores. Por este motivo y muchos otros yo prefiero usar `PDO`, pues `mysqli` de la impresión de algo inacabado o por trozos.

Comment: como instalo el drive mysqlnd uso MAMP en windows

Comment: Si es solo para este uso, puedes hacerlo con [la función que se explica en la respuesta a esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967), donde se trataba precisamente de encontrar una alternativa a la dependencia de un drive externo. Tú puedes incorporar esa función a una clase utilitaria y usarla en cualquiera de tus aplicaciones sin tener que instalar `mysqlnd`

Comment: @A.Cedano Solo como puntualización, el **Controlador Nativo de MySQL** (Mysqlnd) no es software externo a PHP, forma parte de las fuentes oficiales, cosa que la Biblioteca Cliente de MySQL (libmysqlclient) si es externa a php. Es mas desde la versión PHP 5.4.0 es el predeterminado. Como nota: **En las distribuciones oficiales para Windows de PHP 5.3 en adelante, el Controlador Nativo de MySQL está habilitado por defecto, por lo que no se requiere configuración adicional para utilizarlo. En este caso, todas las extensiones de bases de datos MySQL utilizarán el Controlador Nativo de MySQL.**

Comment: @Xerif leyendo el Manual yo siempre había entendido `mysqlnd` como un drive aparte. Quizá sería bueno contar con alguna pregunta que ilustre con más detalle la realidad sobre este drive. Para mí lo que dices en tu comentario es totalmente nuevo.