# ERROR Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object in

Tags: php, mysql

me está saliendo este problema desde hace un día.
Juraría que no toqué nada de este php y hace 2 días funcionaba... y no sé por qué ahora no.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    <?php

    require 'conexion.php';

    if(isset($_GET["id"])){
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM vista_citas WHERE usuario_id = $id";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $response[] = $row;
            }
        }else{
            $response["success"] = false;
        }
    }

    $conn->close();

    echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Es una consulta muy simple, se trae las citas según el usuario_id que se envie, de echo si la pruebo en el phpmyadmin funciona.... 
[image: select en la base de datos]

¿alguien me echa una mano? 
Gracias!

Comment: Se me olvidó decir que si hago la llamada directamente desde la web, devuelve página en blanco

Comment: probablemente algo esté mal en tu string de conexión en tu archivo `conexion.php` porque revisando el archivo de tu descripción no observo errores.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con este código, el cual irá controlando todo el flujo y te dirá el problema que haya ocurrido.

Yo he ido construyendo una variable `$response` que te devolverá, sea los resultados obtenidos de la base de datos, o un array con dos claves: `success`, cuya valor será `FALSE` en caso de error o de datos vacíos, y otra clave `message`, con un mensaje de texto descriptivo de la situación.

Todo lo demás está comentado en el código, pues he implementando consultas preparadas para blindar el código, y he incorporado una función utilitaria (que convendría tener en una clase aparte para cuando la necesites). Esta función resuelve el importante problema de obtener un array asociativo de resultados cuando se usan consultas preparadas en mysqli y no se tiene instalado el drive `mysqlnd` (para más detalles sobre esto puedes leer esta pregunta y su respuesta: [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967)).

He aquí el código. Lo esencial está comentado. Espero te sirva.

```
   /*
        *Podemos usar simplemente empty para evaluar si :
            - se pasó la clave id
            - si ésta tiene algún valor
        *Se hará mediante un operador ternario
    */

    $id=(empty($_GET["id"])) ? NULL : $_GET["id"];
    /*
        *Evaluamos si hay algo en $id
        *Nótese que el require está dentro de esta condición, 
        *ya que si no hay nada en $id no tendría sentido
        *usar la conexión a la BD
        *Así respetamos una regla muy básica: no incluyas nada que no vayas a usar
    */
    if ($id){
        require 'conexion.php';
        /*
            *Conviene evaluar la conexión. Quizá en tu archivo conexion.php
            *cambiaron las credenciales o algo y por eso tu código actual no funciona
        */
        if($conn){
            /* 
                *Vamos a dar seguridad al código usando consultas preparadas
                *Nunca se debería pasar un dato proveniente de una fuente externa
                *directamente en una consulta SQL para que sea ejecutada
                *Esto permitiría que usuarios mal intencionados manipulen los datos escritos
                *para inyectar posible código dañino, el cual se ejecutaría sin control alguno
                *Se trata por tanto de un grave riesgo de seguridad
                *Las consultas preparadas son muy fáciles, se hacen en dos pasos:
                *Paso 1: En la instrucción SQL se cambian los valores reales por marcadores ?
            */

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM vista_citas WHERE usuario_id = ?";
            /* Se manda a preparar la consulta antes escrita*/
            $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
            /*
                *Paso 2: Se pasan los valores reales aparte mediante un método que existe para eso
                *La "i" indica que la columna en cuestión es del tipo (i)nteger en la base de datos
                *Aquí se pasarían tantos tipos de datos/variables como hubiera en la consulta
                *Como sólo hay uno, pasamos uno
            */
            $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
            $stmt->execute();
            /*
                *Almacenamos los datos pasando el resultado de la consulta 
                *a una función propia que hemos creado, la cual nos crea un array
                *asociativo de columnas/valores de cada fila encontrada
                *Existe un método que hace eso, pero a veces no viene instalado en PHP
                *Por eso he optado por esta función, la cual se puede incorporar
                *a una clase utilitaria 
            */
            $datos=fetch_assoc($stmt);

            /*
                *Nótese que hemos prescindido de row_count
                *porque si no hay datos, nuestra función fetch_assoc nos devolverá
                *un array vacío cuando no se encuentre ningún dato
                *En la línea que sigue usamos un ternario para evaluar si $datos está vacío
                *lo cual significará que no hubo datos en la consulta.
            */
            $response=($datos) ? $datos : array("success"=>FALSE, "message"=> "No se encontraron registros");
            /*Cerramos recursos*/
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();

        }else{
                $response=array("success"=> FALSE, "message" => "Hay problemas con la conexión");                       
        }
    }else{
                $response=array("success" => FALSE, "message" => "No hay datos en el GET");                     
    }


echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);


/*
    *Función auxiliar para devolver resultados asociativos
    *ante la dificultad que se presenta cuando se usan consultas preparadas
    *y no se tiene instalado el driver mysqlnd
    *Conviene incorporar esta función a una clase utilitaria
*/

function fetch_assoc ($stmt){
    $result=array();
    $meta = $stmt->result_metadata(); 
    while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) 
    { 
        $params[] = &$row[$field->name]; 
    } 

    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_result'), $params); 

    while ($stmt->fetch()) { 
        foreach($row as $key => $val) 
        { 
            $c[$key] = $val; 
        } 
        $result[] = $c; 
    } 
    return $result;
}
```