# Mi Consulta SQL da un resultado errado

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy intentando esto:

```
$email=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$pwd=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$cons='SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE email=? AND password=?';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($cons);
if($stmt){
    $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$pwd);
}
else{
echo "mm";
}
if($stmt->execute()){
    $filas=$stmt->num_rows;
    echo $stmt->error;

    if($filas>0){
        header('Location: consola.php');
    }
    else{
        echo $filas;
        echo $filas->error;
        echo $filas->errno;
    }
}
else{
    echo $stmt->error;
    echo "sss";

}

$conn->close();
```

Es una modificación a otro código que era mas vulnerable a las inyecciones SQL así que decidí usar sentencias preparadas y el `bind_param` sospecho que el problema está en `$filas=$stmt->num_rows;` porque cuando le doy `echo` imprime 0 obviamente que verifique que lo que escribí en los inputs estuvieran en la tabla . Además quiero saber que otro consejo tienen para la seguridad del código

Comment: mejor usa laravel tendrias menos errores que corregir (no comprendo exactamente el error) como estos y te enfocarias mas a los principales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias cosas en el código, las iré comentando por el orden en que las voy encontrando y al final te propongo una solución:

1. Si usas consultas preparadas, no necesitas `real_escape_string`. Actualmente las consultas preparadas son una poderosa herramienta que hacen incluso lo que ésta función no hace en algunos casos. Sí, está demostrado que en ciertos casos esta función no te ayuda a escapar de nada.
2. Lo que sí deberías verificar es si las variables se pasaron en el `POST`, usaremos `empty` para ello, y un operador ternario.
3. Desde el momento en que preparas la consulta, debes referirte a la variable que se crea al llamar `prepare` para cualquier operación relativa a los resultados.
4. No le veo sentido a evaluar también el `execute`, con evaluar la preparación basta. A partir de ahí tendrás a lo sumo `0` filas si no encuentra datos, pero difícilmente un resultado `FALSE`. Además la lógica de esa parte (donde se evalúa `if($stmt->execute()){`)  parece estar invertida.
5. Todas las evaluaciones que haces luego de una posible obtención de datos en la consulta son ilógicas. He corregido/ordenado toda esa parte para que, si el número de filas es mayor que `0` redirija a la página, y si no, imprima mensajes adecuados.
6. Hay algo muy importante con respecto al uso de `num_rows`. El Manual de PHP dice que: *El comportamiento de `mysqli_num_rows()` depende de si es que se utilizan resultsets con o sin buffer. En caso de emplearlos sin buffer **`mysqli_num_rows()` no retornará el número de filas correcto hasta que todas las filas del resultado hayan sido recuperadas**.*  Esto significa que, para obtener el número de filas una vez ejecutada la consulta, debes meter los resultados en el buffer. Para esto, puedes **invocar a `store_result()` antes de usar `num_rows`, de lo contrario, te arrojará siempre `0` filas aunque haya resultados**.
7. Como nota, si lo único que te interesa saber es si existen registros, lo correcto sería hacer un `SELECT COUNT(*)`, es la forma más óptima para verificar la existencia de registros en tablas. No he modificado la consulta, para no alterar demasiado tu código. Lo comento aquí para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Propongo este código:

```
$email=(empty($_POST['email']))    ? NULL : $_POST['email'];
$pwd  =(empty($_POST['password'])) ? NULL : $_POST['password'];

if ($email && $pwd && $conn){
    $sql='SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE email=? AND password=?';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt){
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$pwd);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $filas=$stmt->num_rows;
        if($filas>0){
            $stmt->close();
            $conn->close();
            header('Location: consola.php');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "No se encontraron registros";
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Error en la consulta: ".$stmt->error;
    }   
}
else
{
    echo "Falta alguno de los datos del POST o la conexión es nula";
}
```

Comment: el output es no se encontraron registros es decir no se encontraron filas

Comment: @ger en la respuesta original se me había escapado algo muy importante. He hecho una edición al código donde he puesto después de `$stmt->execute();` la siguiente línea, `$stmt->store_result();`, por lo que he explicado en el **punto 6  de la respuesta** (editada): **después del `execute` hay que almacenar los resultados en el buffer, de lo contrario `num_rows` dará `0` aunque haya datos**. Quizá cogiste el código sin esa línea y por eso te está dando `0`. Compara el código actual con tu código para verificar si es así o  no.

Comment: correcto muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: otra cosa se me olvidó decir que al resultado de la consulta hay que ponerla de `fetch_assoc` para luego meterlo en una sesión pero no funciona que puedo hacer??

Comment: @ger, si quieres leer los datos de la consulta como dices, puedes hacer algo como esto: `while ($fila = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $fila["email"]." - ".$fila["password"]);
    }` pero OJO, eso no sería compatible con la redirección que aparece en tu código. De todos modos, eso sería cuestión de otra pregunta. Puedes revisar cómo se usa `fetch_assoc` leyendo [lo que dice el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) y revisando los ejemplos.

Comment: arroja el error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()`

Comment: @ger claro, claro. Como te decía, este es otro asunto. Usar `fetch_assoc` con consultas preparadas en MySQLi es una de las cosas que me hacen preferir a PDO. Si no tienes un driver suplementario se te hace complicado. Puedes probar así: `$stmt->execute(); $stmt->get_result();  if ($stmt->num_rows>0){ while ($fila = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) { echo $fila["email"]." - ".$fila["password"]); } }` Si dice que `get_result` no existe significa que no tienes ese driver y deberás implementar tu propia solución, [como se explica aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967).