# No puedo filtrar información de una tabla usando el id de otra, con variables de session

Tags: php, javascript

No se como hacer que me funcionen el filtrar información cuando el curso ya esta relacionado con el id del usuario, uso una variable de sesión pero no se como mostrarlo

```
<?php

session_start();
//Conexion
include("conexion.php");
$_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']; 

// SELECCIONE TODOS LOS CURSOS DONDE EL ID DEL USUARIO SEA IGUAL A  $_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']
//SQL
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE ID_USUARIO='$_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']'";

//Resultado de la SQL
$result = $conn->query($SQL);

if($result->num_rows > 0){

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $ID=$row['ID_CURSO'];
        $NOMBRE=$row['NOMBRE'];
        $INSTRUCTOR= $row['INSTRUCTOR'];        


   }     
}else
{

    $_SESSION["ERROR"]= "NO";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Ese es el código para relacionarlo con la tabla , pero ahora quiero mostrar la información.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema esta en la interpolacion de string, escribes:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE ID_USUARIO='$_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']'";
```

Lo cual no genera el resultado que buscas, para interpolar correctamente la variable de sesion deberias hacer lo siguiente:

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE ID_USUARIO='${_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']}'";
```

De todas formas lo que recomendaria es crear un statement preparado de SQL y luego pasar la variable de sesion como parametro, de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php

session_start();

//Conexion
include("conexion.php");

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE ID_USUARIO=?";

//Preparar el statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($SQL);

//Asociar parametro
$stmt->bind_param("s",$_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']);

$stmt->execute();

//Resultado de la SQL
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows > 0){

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $ID=$row['ID_CURSO'];
        $NOMBRE=$row['NOMBRE'];
        $INSTRUCTOR= $row['INSTRUCTOR'];        


   }     
}else
{

    $_SESSION["ERROR"]= "NO";
}

$result->close();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

**NOTA:** el metodo `get_result` no funciona si el driver `mysqlnd` no se encuentra instalado (opte por mostrar este metodo proque era el de mas directa implementacion, si no lo puede utilizar debera [asociar los resultados](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) y luego hacer [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) por cada registro  ).

Comment: Esta es la mejor respuesta, porque implementa un código seguro contra la **Inyección SQL**. Pero hay que tener en cuenta que `get_result` no funciona si no tiene instalado el driver `mysqlnd`. [Ver esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967) y su respuesta para una alternativa en ese caso.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaracion, si bien sabia de ese detalle como en la consulta utiliza el * y no conozco la estructura de la tabla, considere que la manera mas directa de adaptarlo era utilizando ese metodo. Voy a agregar una aclaracion al respecto.

Answer (score 0):

lo que sucede es que el momento que el query se ejecuta, automaticamente se escapan los valores `[]` por motivos de seguridad y prevencion de inyeccion sql, entonces no te deja ejecutar, por ende debes intentar con esto:

```
<?php

session_start();
//Conexion
include("conexion.php");
$_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']; 

// SELECCIONE TODOS LOS CURSOS DONDE EL ID DEL USUARIO SEA IGUAL A  $_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']
//SQL
$usuario = $_SESSION['ID_USUARIO'];

$SQL = "SELECT * FROM cursos WHERE ID_USUARIO='$usuario'";

//Resultado de la SQL
$result = $conn->query($SQL);

if($result->num_rows > 0){

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $ID=$row['ID_CURSO'];
        $NOMBRE=$row['NOMBRE'];
        $INSTRUCTOR= $row['INSTRUCTOR'];        


   }     
}else
{

    $_SESSION["ERROR"]= "NO";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: lo probare, pero y al momento de mostrar en otra pagina los resultado ? que tendria que hacer

Comment: es normal como lo venias haciendo, solo que al la variable ´$usuario´ le asignas el valor de la session para poder meterlo en la consulta

Comment: lo hice como dijiste broth pero al mostrarlo no me aparece resultados

Comment: y ese usuario si tiene registro en la tabla cursos ?

Comment: si , ejemplo es Juan1 su Id=1

Comment: entonces en la tabla cursos ya esta en un registro el id de juan+

Comment: has un echo $_SESSION['ID_USUARIO']; a ver que te esta trayendo, lo mas probable es que no este trayendo el "1"