# ¿Como puedo instalar la libreria Mysqlnd para evitar error al realizar consultas mediante un WEB-SERVICE?

Tags: php, mysql

He estado buscando información en todo tipo de foros y paginas, incluso en la documentación de **PHP**, pero no encuentro como puedo instalar esta libreria, ya que manejo `Web-Services` para poder hacer consultas a mis bases de datos en `Mysql` pero por defecto tiene instalada la librería `libmysql`, y por esto no puedo ejecutar dichas consultas.

Por favor gente, alguna pista o documentación para poder hacer correctamente la actualización.

**Versión de Mysqlnd instalado:**

> mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407

**Este es el error que me arroja el servidor al realizar una consulta al no tener actualizado el Mysqlnd:**

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**
Segun la documentación en **PHP**, se debe instalar la libreria mediante el siguiente comando pero no se en donde se aplica, ya que uso un servidor con Unix:

`$ ./configure --with-mysqli = mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql = mysqlnd --with-mysql = mysqlnd`

Comment: [Aquí tienes una función que hace lo mismo que `get_result`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114105/29967). Se puede usar como una alternativa en casos como el tuyo. Puedes, si quieres, incorporar esa función a una clase utilitaria y usarla en tu aplicación sin ningún problema.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si ya había visto que se podía cambiar por otra función, pero realmente necesito cambiar la librería, trabajo con bastantes funciones y todas funcionan con `Mysqli`, me tomaría bastante tiempo buscar un método que las reemplace y luego cambiarlas :(