# Problemas con fetch() fetch_array()

Tags: php, mysqli, sql

estoy teniendo problemas con `fetch()` `fetch_array()` estoy trabajando con sentencias preparadas desde ayer soy nuevo en ello y tengo este codigo que practicamente al hacer `fetch()` no me esta arrojando nada no se que estoy haciendo mal, si lo hago normal sin sentencias preparadas si me arroja resultado es decir `$query=$conexion->query()` etc...

ojala me puedan ayudar e aqui mi **codigo:**

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $profile=$_GET['id'];//recojer id 

     $infouser="SELECT * FROM registro WHERE id=?";

        $stmt = $conexion->prepare($infouser);//preparar sentencia

          $stmt->bind_param("i",$profile);

           $stmt->execute();

         $stmt->store_result();

         if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {


          $userInfo = $stmt->fetch();//si aqui pongo fetch_array() me lanza error

            //aqui solo me imprime nombre, el resultado esperado seria nombre:Fulano 
          echo "nombre ".$userInfo["nombre"];
          $stmt->close();
```

ya googlee un poco pero aun asi no entiendo que pasa ojala me puedan ayudar ya que he intentado una y mil maneras y no consigo nasda Gracias de ante mano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En `mysqli` obtener los resultados cuando se usan consultas preparadas es un poco más complicado que con PDO. Ello es debido en parte a que una obtención directa de los datos depende de un driver externo a mysqli llamado `mysqlnd`. Cuando tienes ese driver puedes usar el método `get_result` para obtener los resultados en forma de array asociativo u otro.

Como no sé si tienes ese driver, puedes optar por otro método que funciona siempre sin depender de otros drivers.

Consiste en lo siguiente:

- Nombrar en el `SELECT` de una manera explícita las columnas que necesitas. Esto, por lo demás, es una **práctica recomendada** en vez del famoso `SELECT *` que solemos ver por todas partes.
- Usar `bind_result` para asignar el valor de la columna a una variable.
- Leer en un `while` los resultados fila por fila. Este es un punto importante. Por motivos de memoria, las consultas a bases de datos no es que devuelvan de golpe todas las filas (a no ser que sea indicado así de forma explícita), sino que devuelven como un puntero para recorrer los datos fila por fila. Eso haremos con el `while`, pudiendo imprimir los datos directamente o almacenarlos en una variable **solo en el caso de que los necesitemos para pasarlos a otra parte del código**.

El código quedaría así:

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $profile=$_GET['id'];//recojer id 
    $infouser="SELECT nombre FROM registro WHERE id=?";
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($infouser);//preparar sentencia
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$profile);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($nombre);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            echo "nombre: ".$nombre.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Si quieres guardar los datos en un array para usarlo en otra parte del código, puedes entonces hacer lo siguiente:

- Declarar el array antes del `while` que lee cada fila.
- Ir llenando el array dentro del `while`. Le puedes poner como clave el mismo nombre de la columna.

Por ejemplo:

```
    $arrResult=array();

    if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
        $stmt->bind_result($nombre);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            $arrResult[]=array ("nombre"=>$nombre);
        }
    }

    /*Prueba de datos*/
    print_r($arrResult);
```

Tendrás en `$arrResult` un array asociativo hecho a mano.

Nótese que este proceso es más fácil si se contara con el driver `mysqlnd`.

También, la función `get_result` se puede emular, escribiendo tu propia función. [Hay una pregunta aquí que trata ese tema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967). La respuesta aceptada aportó una función que es sucedánea de `get_result`, útil para incorporarla a una posible clase utilitaria o usarla directamente si nos interesa.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: gracias! por compartir tus conocimiento a la comunidad  y a este novato servidor . funciono perffectamnete @A. Cedano

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido @chosen. Gracias también a ti por tus excelentes preguntas. También preguntando se posibilita que aprendamos y la comunidad se enriquece con buenas respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Exitos! @A. Cedano