# Consulta preparada MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

Buenas gente quiero hacer una consulta de ¿Cómo traducir este código en PDO a `MySQLi`? Estoy teniendo problemas de como llevarlo a `MySQLi` alguna idea. Saludos.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE rut = :codigo");
$stmt->bindParam(':codigo',$Codigo);
$stmt->execute();
if($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    echo $row['rut']."*".$row['rut']."*".$row['nombres'];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli`  es un poco diferente a PDO y eso se nota en las consultas preparadas.

Las cosas que difieren son:

- `mysqli` no admite marcadores de `:nombre`, debes usar marcadores de posición `?`
- para hacer el binding debes usar **[`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)**, con dos tipos de parámetros: a la izquirda el tipo de dato de cada columna, a la derecha el valor de la columna. Ver en su enlace cómo se usa cuando son varias columnas de varios tipos de dato. Aquí he puesto una `s` asumiendo que la columna `rut` es de tipo `VARCHAR`
- para leer los datos se usan los métodos `fetch` específicos de `mysqli`... hay varios, como en PDO, pero la sintaxis es distinta. Pero en `mysqli` se echa de menos la facilidad con que se recuperan los datos en este tipo de consultas cuando usas PDO. De hecho, para obtener resultados asociativos en consultas preparadas, si no tienes el driver `mysqlnd` instalado se te complica ese proceso que parece tan simple.

Sabiendo eso, propongo tres soluciones:

#### Solución 1

Puedes recuperar los resultados mediante el uso del método [**`bind_result`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php). Puede ser interesante cuando en el `SELECT` hay pocas columnas. Eso sí, tienes que indicar de forma explícita las columnas que quieres para asignar cada una a una variable. En cualquier caso, siempre es conveniente indicar de forma explícita las columnas que queremos seleccionar, evitando el uso de <s>`SELECT *`</s>:

```
$sql="SELECT nombre, rut FROM usuario WHERE rut = ?";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$Codigo);
    $stmt->bind_result($nombre, $rut);
    $stmt->execute();

    while ($stmt->fetch) {
      echo $rut."*".$rut."*".$nombre;
    }
}else{
    echo "Error en la consulta: ";
}
```

El problema de `bind_result` es que cuando hay muchas columnas tienes que hacer el binding una por una.

---

#### Solución 2

Puedes usar algo parecido al resultado array asociativo de PDO, usando **[`fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)**  combinado con `get_result`. Sólo que esta última función está ligada al drive `mysqlnd`. Si no está instalado este código no funcionará:

```
$sql="SELECT nombre, rut FROM usuario WHERE rut = ?";
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$Codigo);
    $stmt->bind_result($nombre, $rut);
    $stmt->execute();
    $datos = $stmt->get_result(); //requiere mysqlnd
    while ( $row = $datos->fetch_assoc() ) {
      echo $row['rut']."*".$row['rut']."*".$row['nombres'];
    }
}else{
    echo "Error en la consulta: ";
}
```

---

#### Solución 3:

Implementar tu propia función que emule a `get_result`. Esto es particularmente útil cuando necesitas trasladar los resultados a otra parte. O cuando trabajas en un `SELECT con varias columnas.

Más detalles sobre esta tercera vía son explicados aquí:

- [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, tu código me da el siguiente error por algo del Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_assoc()

Comment: require "Conexion.php";
//require "Config.php";
$Codigo = $_POST["Codigo"];

if (!empty($Codigo)) {
  
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE rut = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$Codigo);
if ($stmt->execute()){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo $row['rut']."*".$row['rut']."*".$row['nombres'];
    }
}else{
    echo "Error en la consulta";
}


}

Comment: @FelipeLarraguibel es cierto, en `mysqli` no puedes usar `fetch_assoc` con consultas preparadas como se hace con PDO. Debes usar `bind_result` como explico al final o usar una función propia, o usar `get_result` primero, sólo que este no funciona si no tienes el driver `mysqlnd`. Ahora edito la respuesta.

Comment: muchas gracias para este caso me quede con la solución 1.

Comment: @FelipeLarraguibel para consultas con pocas columnas es lo más práctico. No olvides marcar como resulta la pregunta indicando la respuesta que más haya ayudado a resolver tu problema. Saludos.

Comment: como doy la pregunta finalizada y marcar la respuesta correcta?

Comment: @FelipeLarraguibel basta para aceptar la respuesta que le des clic en la palomita que esta justo a lado izquierdo de la que quieres marcar

Answer (score 0):

Deberías probar de este modo

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE rut = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s',$Codigo);
$stmt->execute();

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt))
{
    echo $fila['rut']."*".$fila['rut']."*".$fila['nombres'];
}
```

**OBSERVACIONES**

1. En mysqli los marcadores son con el símbolo de: `?` y se les conoce como marcadores de posición
2. el método de bindeo se escribe así: `bind_param()` recibe como primer argumento entre comillas `s` identificando si se trata de un string o una `i` si es un integer y después la variable
3. posterior usas el método `execute()`
4. para recorrer todos los registros podemos usar un while, donde declaramos una variable `$fila` a la cual igualamos con el método `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` y a este le pasamos la variable `$stmt`
5. Por último con un `echo` imprimimos, de la variable fila, cada columna que va leyendo

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in hay un error ahi en lo que dices

Answer (score 0):

seria mas o menos asi

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT campo1,campo2 FROM usuario WHERE rut =?");//aqui lo adecuado seria poner los campos que nececitas
$stmt->bind_param("i",$Codigo);//aqui estoy suponiendo que el valor de la variable codigo es un entero, por eso pongo i entre comillas, si fuera lo comtrario osea un string tienes que poner una s
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($campo1,$campo2);//con bind_result traeras los campos espesificados en el select , nota:tienen que ser en el mismo orden
    $row->fetch()) {
        printf("%s %s\n", $campo1, $campo2);
    }

    /* cerrar la sentencia */
    $stmt->close();
}
/* cerrar la conexión */
$conn->close();
```