# Como obtener los datos de un SELECT con Sentencias Preparadas PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statements

Realizo un `SELECT` para averiguar si existe un usuario con un email y contraseña usando las **sentencias preparadas de PHP** (Prepared Statement).

El problema es que después de verificar que sí existe, **necesito obtener el SSID** de ese usuario para ponerlo en su `$_SESSION`, y para eso necesito hacer algo similar al `MySQLi Fetch Assoc` **pero que sirva en mi caso**, que uso sentencias preparadas.

Mi código:

```
// Preparar el SELECT
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tab_users WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $email, $mdpass);

// Ejecutar el SELECT y comprobar
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->num_rows >= "1") {
  //Si hay 1 registro, recoger los datos aquí (es lo que necesito)
} else {
  array_push($errors, "Correo electrónico o contraseña incorrectos");
}

// Cerrar las conexiones
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con `get_result()` obtienes los valores de una sentencia preparada y posterior con el método `fetch_assoc()` vuelves el conjunto de datos en un array asociativo

Posterior con el uso de `num_rows < 1` verificas que si no hay registros se mande un mensaje

ahora con un bucle while, recorres los valores y los recuperas por su clave o nombre de columnna de este modo

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tab_users WHERE email = ? AND pass = ?");
$query->bind_param("ss", $email, $mdpass);
$query->execute();

$resultado = $query->get_result();

if($resultado->num_rows < 1){
    echo "sin valores"; 
}else{
    while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $fila["nombreColumnaUno"];
    echo $fila["nombreColumnaDos"];
}
}
```

Comment: Solamente señalar que `get_result` funciona **únicamente** cuando tenemos instalado el driver `mysqlnd`. En caso contrario, la obtención de los resultados en mysqli cuando usamos consultas preparadas se es mucho más complicada que en PDO, sobre todo cuando se van a manejar muchas columnas en los resultados. En la pregunta [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967) se aportó una respuesta para resolver la situación en estos casos.