# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mpdf

Tengo un problema en mPDF a la hora de hacer mi conexión, la pruebo en Xampp y funciona de manera correcta pero al pasarla a mi servidor salta un error en "get_result()"

```
$query = "select r.id_usuario,r.id_rubro,r.cantidad,r.n_cotizacion, u.nombre, r.nombreRubro, r.descripcion,r.precio, r.precio*r.cantidad as total, r.fecha from usuario u,rubros r where u.id_usuario=r.id_usuario and r.n_cotizacion = ".$n_cot.";";
$prepare = $conn->prepare($query);
$prepare->execute();
$resultSet = $prepare->get_result();



while ($rubros[] = $resultSet->fetch_array());
$resultSet->close();
$prepare->close();
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Es posible que `$prepare = $conn->prepare($query);` esto esté dando un warning y que por eso  esto `$resultSet = $prepare->get_result();` te esté dando un error y no lo veas porque en el servidor tengas los errores desactivados?

Comment: El error *`Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() ...`* ocurre porque **`get_result()` no existe en tu instalación de PHP**. Si revisas el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) leerás que este método existe cuando tienes instalado el driver `mysqlnd`, el cual no viene en muchos entornos PHP y hay que instalarlo aparte. Si quieres una función que emule a `get_result` podrías consultar [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967) y sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

El error `Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() ...` ocurre porque `get_result()` no existe en tu instalación de PHP.

Si revisas el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) leerás que para usar este método necesitas tener instalado (y cargado) el driver `mysqlnd`, el cual no viene en muchos entornos PHP y hay que instalarlo aparte.

Si quieres una función que emule a `get_result` podrías consultar la pregunta [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967) y sus respuestas.

Este código te servirá para determinar si la función existe:

```
var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_stmt_get_result'));
```

Y para ver si tienes el driver `mysqlnd` instalado pero no cargado, puedes poner esto en un archivo:

```
phpinfo();  #Sólo verificar, no dejes esto permanente en ningún archivo
```

Y buscar dentro de la información todo lo relativo a `mysqlnd` y su estado. O, puedes revisar el archivo `php. ini`. Pero, mucho ojo con las cambios que hagas en ese archivo, porque es un archivo de configuración.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, conseguí resolver el problema ya que era un error de compatibilidad en la librería de mPDF  o al menos eso creo ya que fue cuestión de actualizar la librería a la versión 6.0 ya que yo tenia la versión 5.7