# Como traer datos de mysql con prepare

Tags: php, mysql

Estimados estoy realizando la siguiente consulta en PHP, utilizando la siguiente linea de codigo,pero resulta ser que me da el siguiente error

Undefined variable: result on line 27
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on line 27

Pero si hago la consulta con un solo parametro es decir "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = ?", no me da el error y muestra los datos correctamente.

```
<?php
include 'logica/bd.php';
$conexion = new mysqli(DB_SERVIDOR,DB_USUARIO,DB_CLAVE,DB_BASE)
or die(mysql_error());
$conexion->set_charset("utf8");
$conexion->query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = ? AND sku = ?");
$id = 2;
$sku = 'ECU-00001';

$query->bind_param("is", $id , $sku);
$query->execute();
$meta = $query->result_metadata();
while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()){
    $params[] = &$row[$field->name];
}

call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_result'), $params);
while ($query->fetch()) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val){
        $c[$key] = $val;
    }
    $result[] = $c;
}

for($x=0;$x<count($result);$x++){
    $fila = $result[$x];
    echo $fila['id'];
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que implementes el código dentro de una función, con algunas variantes, pues mareas demasiado los datos en tu código actual.

Puedes crear esta función, que podría ser incorporada a una clase utilitaria para reutilizar en proyectos grandes o en proyectos compartidos.

```
function custom_get_result($stmt) {
    $mResult = array();
    $stmt->store_result();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $stmt->num_rows; $i++ ) {
        $metadata = $stmt->result_metadata();
        $params = array();
        while ( $field = $metadata->fetch_field() ) {
            $params[] = &$mResult[$i][ $field->name ];
        }
        call_user_func_array( array( $stmt, 'bind_result' ), $params );
        $stmt->fetch();
    }
    return $mResult;
}
```

Ahora, para usarla en tu contexto:

```
include 'logica/bd.php';
$conexion = new mysqli(DB_SERVIDOR,DB_USUARIO,DB_CLAVE,DB_BASE)
or die(mysql_error());
$conexion->set_charset("utf8");
$conexion->query("SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES'");
$query = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = ? AND sku = ?");
$id = 2;
$sku = 'ECU-00001';

$query->bind_param("is", $id , $sku);
$query->execute();
$mData=custom_get_result($query);
#Test
var_dump($mData);
```

En `$mData` tendrás un arreglo asociativo con los resultados y podrás leerlo o pasarlo a otro contexto de tu código.

---

- Fuente: [La respuesta de @D.Bulten](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/114105/29967) en la pregunta: *[¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967)*

Comment: Con respecto a la funcion que comentas mas arriba, cual es la forma de pasarle la query al llamar la funcion y como le paso los parametros basado en lo que yo estoy haciendo actualmente, me parece excelente la funcion.

Comment: @JonathanAlarcon lo he explicado en la segunda parte de la respuesta a partir de donde dice: ***Ahora, para usarla en tu contexto:***