# Cómo obtener datos de columnas con una consulta preparada usando while

Tags: php

Me interesa obtener los datos de la cuenta usando while para poderlos mostrar... ¿Qué le hace falta al código para cumplir la función?

```js
 
 $email = "";
 $password = "";
 
 
 // EN LA BASE DE DATOS:
 
 // account_email | account_password | account_id | account_photo etc...
 
 
 // ME GUSTARÍA ENTONCES OBTENER LOS DATOS TALES COMO LA ID LA FOTO ETC... SI LA CONDICIÓN DE CORREO Y CONTRASEÑA SE CUMPLEN
 
 
 $login_get = "SELECT FROM $users WHERE account_email = ? AND account_password = ?";
 
    $login_result = mysqli_prepare($base, $login_get); 
   
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($login_result, "ss", $email, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($login_result); 
  
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($account);
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($login_result);  
    mysqli_stmt_close($login_result);
```

Comment: 2 cosas: 1.- Tu SQL es incorrecto, te falta indicar que columnas quieres recuperar (*SELECT columna(s) FROM tu tu Tabla*) y 2.- ¿Qué has intentado al respecto?, además como extra ¿de dónde sale `$users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El uso de `while` al leer resultados obtenidos en una consulta lanzada con la API `mysqli` sólo es justificado **cuando esperas varias filas**. ¿Por qué? Porque `mysqli` devuelve un recurso, y `while` te permite ir moviendo el puntero de ese recurso para obtener cada fila con el método `fetch_` apropiado <sup>1</sup>.

Entendido eso, cuando usas consultas preparadas, es necesario usar `bind_result` para indicar a qué variables van a ser asignados los resultados obtenidos de cada columna, por eso **es fundamental indicar en el `SELECT` de modo explícito las columnas que quieres obtener**.

Asumiendo que estas son las columnas de tu tabla:

```
account_email | account_password | account_id | account_photo
```

El código quedaría así (si hay más columnas las agregas al `SELECT` y **destinas por cada una una variable en el `bind_result`**):

```
$email = "";
$password = "";
 
 
$login_get = "SELECT account_email, account_password, account_id, account_photo FROM $users WHERE account_email = ? AND account_password = ?";
 
$login_result = mysqli_prepare($base, $login_get); 
   
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($login_result, "ss", $email, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($login_result); 
/*
   Aquí se indica en orden del SELECT 
   a qué variable va el resultado de cada columna
*/

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($email, $password, $id, $photo);

/*
   Definimos un array para guardar cada fila de resultados
*/
$mData=array();
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($login_result)) {
    $thisRow=array(
                    'account_email'=>$email, 
                    'account_password'=>$password, 
                    'account_id'=>$id, 
                    'account_photo'=>$photo,
                   );   
    $mData[]=$thisRow;
}
mysqli_stmt_close($login_result); 

/* Usar $mData*/
var_dump($mData);
```

Como ya dije, el asunto del `while` **sólo es necesario cuando esperas varias filas de resultados**. Si esperas una sola fila, no tienes que mover el puntero en un `while`, solamente aplicar fetch_ una sola vez y ya tendrás los datos que esperas, puesto que **no hay más filas y por tanto no necesitas seguir moviendo el puntero**.

A decir verdad, la lectura de resultados cuando usas consultas preparadas es un poco rollo en `mysqli` (PDO es menos complicado). Si te interesa implementar una lectura más sencilla, puedes incorporar la función que está en la respuesta aceptada de esta pregunta: *[¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967)*.

---

**Notas:**

1. A no ser que uses `fetch_all`, el cual te traerá de golpe todas las filas. Pero este método no existe en muchas instalaciones, porque viene con el paquete `mysqlnd`, el cual no está instalado en todos los servidores. Además, este método no es recomendable en contextos donde esperas una gran cantidad de filas, porque podrías tener problemas de desbordamiento de memoria o de rendimiento.