# Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given in

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Cordial saludo equipo espero se encuentren bien quiero pedirles el favor
con lo siguiente que corresponde a crear unos menus en php que interactuan
con Mysql con Phpmyadmin, el error que me muestra es el (mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given), ahora bien el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
require_once("connect/conexion.php");
$consulta="SELECT * FROM menu WHERE estado = 1";
$resy=$con->prepare($consulta);
$resy->execute();
$resy->store_result();
$rows = $resy->num_rows;
?>

<html>
   <head>
     <title>Menú con PHP POO</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css"/>
     <style>
        li{
          width: calc(100% / <?php echo $rows; ?>);
        }
     </style>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="contenedor">
        <header>
          <h1>Página Principal</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
           <?php 
               // while ($fila = $resy->fetch_assoc($resy)) 
               echo $rows;
               
               while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resy))   //$resy, $rows
               {
                echo $fila['nombre_menu'];
                echo '<li><a href="#">'.$fila['nombre_menu'].'</a></li>';
                }
           ?>
          </ul>
        </nav>
       </div>
   </body>

</html>

?>
```

el warning que me muestra es en la siguiente linea de codigo:
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resy))
y dice así:
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object
given ,viendo en internet me dicen que la consulta esta fallando, pero ejecuto
la consulta en el Mysql PhpMyadmin y funciona correctamente, vale aclarar que el wampserver
no me cambia de naranja a verde y hecho todo lo que esta disponible en la red y no me ha sido posible
.
Agradezco la colaboración que me puedan brindar.

Att. Hernán Martínez.

Answer (score 2):

Debes leer un poco más sobre [MySQLi y las consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli-stmt.php).

El problema es que le estás pasando un objeto tipo **stmt** al **fetch** en vez de uno mysqli.

Si bien, se pueden nombrar las variables como uno quiera, es muy común que existan estándares para ciertas variables especiales, como el caso de `$stmt` (statement), más abajo en el código reemplazaré *$resy* por `$stmt` por convención, pero tu lo puedes dejar como `$resy` si deseas.

Por otro lado, recomiendo no usar estilo orientado a objetos y orientado a procedimiento en un mismo código. Usas uno, o usas el otro.

```
<?php

require_once("connect/conexion.php");
$consulta="SELECT * FROM menu WHERE estado = 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare($consulta);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); // <-- Aqui está tu error
$rows = $result->num_rows;
echo $rows;

while($fila = $result->fetch_assoc()) // <-- Usar el estilo orientado a objetos
{
    var_dump($fila); // <-- array asociativo por registro
}
```

Comment: Quizá conviene aclarar que `get_result` no funcionará si el servidor no tiene instalado mysqlnd. En ese caso habría que: 1. Escribir un `SELECT` explícito y vincular cada columna con [`bind_result`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)  o 2. Crear tu propia función para hacer una vinculación de los datos ([ver esta pregunta para más detalles sobre esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/114051/29967)). A mi juicio es un handicap de mysql y no entiendo por qué no hicieron más simple la obtención de resultados de consultas preparadas, al estilo PDO.